# URL atrapalhando requisições ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um sistema que define a url de acordo com o link que o usuário clica, e faz uma requisição ajax e trás o conteúdo só que a url atrapalha a requisição.

Por exemplo: O usuário clica em um link e a url é modificada para `localhost/urlclickada` mas a requisição ajax deve ir para `localhost/sys/funcoes.php` e ela vai para `localhost/urlclickada/sys/funcoes.php`.

Já tentei colocar barra na frente da `url $.post("/sys/funcoes.php")` ou `$.post("../sys/funcoes.php")`.

Comment: sem ver seu código, impossível ajudar...

Answer (score 0):

Tente `$.post("./sys/funcoes.php")`